# Total sql connection consuming by application

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

I have multiple C# applications and all applications use the same database(SQL server 2014) and same credentials(Same connection string). All application run on the same server.

Now, my question is anyhow can I get the total number of SQL connections consuming(current open connection) by particular application right now?

I.e

```
     1. 3 connections open in Application1
     2. 2 connections open in Application2
```

I tried using "App Name" in connection string but I don't know how to get total connection consuming by "App Name"?

Comment: You can use SQL APP_NAME: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189770.aspx in conjunction with https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+number+of+active+connections&ie=&oe=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query the Dynamic Management Views:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*),
    program_name
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_connections cn
LEFT JOIN 
    sys.dm_exec_sessions sn
ON 
    sn.session_id = cn.session_id
GROUP BY 
    program_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found another sql query to get open connection application wise.

```
SELECT count(*),program_name
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses sp 
group by program_name
```